# comma split array only iterating first result with .map

Tags: arrays, reactjs, for-loop, split, map-function

I have a guns.json object that contains an array of objects in my React.js app. I have an array that i created from a comma separated string using the split(',') function. I want my app to recognize one of those strings to match the guns.weapon string in my guns.json object. The code is currently working, however it only iterates one return instead of a result from each array item. only the first array item triggers a return. My for loop appears to not be working correctly.

```js
{this.state.items.map((item, index) => {
  return (
    <div key={index}>
      <List>                               
        {this.state.items[index].squadMembers.map((squadMember, index) => {
          var arr = squadMember.equipment.split(',');
          return (
            <div key={index}>
              <table>
                <tbody>
                  {guns.map((gun, index) => {
                    {for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                      if (arr[i] === gun.weapon) {
                        return (
                          <tr key={index}>                                                                              
                            <td>{gun.weapon}</td>
                            <td>"..."</td>
                            <td>"..."</td>
                          </tr>
                        )
                      }
                    }}
                  })}
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </div>
          )
        })}
      </List>
    </div>                                                                  
  )
})}
```

Comment: Can you post sample data?

Comment: You don't need braces around your for loop. You only need braces around the map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was that in my split(',') function, i forgot to add the space in the argument.
split(', ') removed the space before each item. the return was not iterating after the first value because there was a space preceding each string.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be using reduce in your function, also if you write it well, you can prevent yourself going back in this `indentation hell`.

Suppose `guns` is this array :

```
guns = [{id: 1, name: 'hello'}, {id: 2, name: 'world'}];
```

and your `arr` is :

```
arr = ['hello', 'ajay']
```

Then you can use reduce to get the items which are common in `guns` and `arr`.

```
guns.reduce(function(brr, gun){
    arr.forEach(function(item){
        if(item === gun.name){
            brr.push(item);
        }
    })
    return brr;
}, [])
```

So what you should do is (might create some issue of braces/indentation etc. so just giving you the idea):

```
{this.state.items.map((item, index) => {
  return (
    <div key={index}>
      <List>                               
        {this.state.items[index].squadMembers.map((squadMember, index) => {
            var arr = squadMember.equipment.split(',');
            const itemsToRender = guns.reduce(function(brr, gun){
                arr.forEach(function(item){
                if(item === gun.name){
                    brr.push(gun);
                }
            })
            return brr;
            }, []);


            return (
              <div key={index}>
                    <table>
                        <tbody>
                            {itemsToRender
                                 .map((gun, index) => {
                                     return (
                                         <tr key={index}>                                                                                
                                             <td>{gun.weapon}</td>
                                             <td>"..."</td>
                                             <td>"..."</td>
                                            </tr>
                                      )
                             }
                             </tbody>
                         </table>
                     </div>
                  )})}
            </List>
        </div>                                                                  
    )
})}
```

Comment: thank you for the suggestion, it turns out it was a very simple solution where i neglected to remove the space before the other items in the string. split(', ') instead of split(',')